# Bad Access Code on PhysicsJoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, exc-bad-access

I can't seem to figure out why the bad access code appears, can someone help?
I have code to add a sprite and an emitter node, each of which have their own physics bodies. Now, the sprite moves around the map, and there is a camera that follows it. The sprite's parent is `myWorld`, which itself is a child of the scene. When I attempt to add a physicsJoint between the moving sprite (which is not moving when the joint is initialized), I get a bad access code. Here is the code:

```
    self.sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];

    self.sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self.sprite setScale:.5];
    self.sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.sprite.size];
    self.sprite.physicsBody.mass = 50;
    self.sprite.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    self.sprite.name = @"sprite";
    self.sprite.zPosition = 5;
    self.sprite.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(300, 0);
    self.sprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = plane;
    self.sprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ships;
    self.sprite.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;


    NSString *firePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyParticle" ofType:@"sks"];
    self.smokeTrail = [SKEmitterNode node];
    self.smokeTrail = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:firePath];
    self.smokeTrail.position = CGPointMake(self.sprite.position.x-2*self.sprite.size.width/5, self.sprite.position.y);
    [self.smokeTrail setScale:1];
    self.smokeTrail.zPosition = self.sprite.zPosition-1;
    self.smokeTrail.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.smokeTrail.frame.size];
    self.smokeTrail.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    self.smokeTrail.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    self.smokeTrail.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 0;

    smokeJoint = [SKPhysicsJointFixed jointWithBodyA:self.sprite.physicsBody bodyB:self.smokeTrail.physicsBody anchor:CGPointMake(self.smokeTrail.position.x+self.smokeTrail.frame.size.width/2,self.smokeTrail.position.y)];

    ...

    [myWorld setScale:0.4f];

    self.sprite.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);

    [self addChild:myWorld];
    [self addChild:backgroundNode];
    [self addChild:buttonDown];
    [self addChild:buttonUp];
    [myWorld addChild:blueBox];
    [self addChild:self.speed];
    [self addChild:self.altitude];
    [self addChild:self.darkBlueWave];
    [self addChild:self.lightBlueWave];

    [myWorld addChild:self.smokeTrail];
    [myWorld addChild:self.sprite];
    [myWorld addChild:randomNode];
    [myWorld addChild:camera];

    [self.physicsWorld addJoint:smokeJoint];  // Bad Access Code Happens Here
```

Comment: is smokeJoint nil perhaps?

Comment: I ran a conditional to test it. It's not nil.

Comment: anything in the log? Can you post the call stack?

Comment: Did you add myWorld to the scene? Both physics bodies must be in the scene before you can add a joint to the world.

Comment: I don't have access to my computer right now, but theres nothing special going on in the call stack (ill post it later). And yes, myWorld is in the scene (the game works without the joint)